# How do I parse a dropdownlist returned as a HTML string in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a HTML string like this. I want to get the selected value, which, in this case is `AN`:

```
<SELECT id=ddl_Freq name=ddl_Freq><OPTION selected value=AN>Annually</OPTION> <OPTION value=BM>Bi-Monthly</OPTION> <OPTION value=MO>Monthly</OPTION> <OPTION value=OT>One Time</OPTION> <OPTION value=QT>Quarterly</OPTION> <OPTION value=WE>Weekly</OPTION></SELECT>
```

which when formatted looks like this:

```
<SELECT id=ddl_Freq name=ddl_Freq>
    <OPTION selected value=AN>Annually</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=BM>Bi-Monthly</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=MO>Monthly</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=OT>One Time</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=QT>Quarterly</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=WE>Weekly</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

I tried these two approaches, but I wasn't successful.

#### Approach 1: JavaScript

```
DdlHtml = document.createElement('select');
DdlHtml.innerHTML = RawDdlString;
item = DdlHtml.options[DdlHtml.selectedIndex].value;
```

This fails because the string already contains `<SELECT>` and `</SELECT>` tags.

#### Approach 2: jQuery

```
DdlHtml2 = $.parseHTML(RawDdlString);
item = DdlHtml2.options[DdlHtml2.selectedIndex].value;
```

This also didn't work as `DdlHtml2.options` is undefined.

How do I parse this string which contains HTML for a dropdownlist in either Javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the string in a jQuery selector:

```
$(function() {
    var $select = $("<SELECT id=ddl_Freq name=ddl_Freq><OPTION selected value=AN>Annually</OPTION> <OPTION value=BM>Bi-Monthly</OPTION> <OPTION value=MO>Monthly</OPTION> <OPTION value=OT>One Time</OPTION> <OPTION value=QT>Quarterly</OPTION> <OPTION value=WE>Weekly</OPTION></SELECT");
   console.log($select.val()); 
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/SHbqv/1/) is an example fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

$('#ddl_Freq').val()

Answer (score 0):

without jQuery,

```
<SELECT id=ddl_Freq name=ddl_Freq>
    <OPTION selected value=AN>Annually</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=BM>Bi-Monthly</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=MO>Monthly</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=OT>One Time</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=QT>Quarterly</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=WE>Weekly</OPTION>
</SELECT>

var x = document.getElementById("ddl_Freq");
x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;



Output:
    "AN"
```

link to jsbin snippet:

```
http://jsbin.com/omuxow/1/edit
```